# Desktop edition to Server edition and support

Tags: installation, server, distro-recommendation

- Ubuntu Desktop will receive 3 years of support, while Ubuntu Server will be supported for 5 years.

Well this is what ubuntu server faq says. So my question is can I change a desktop edition 
to server edition and change the support from 3 to 5 years? I hope the support here means the packages update that ubuntu provides. Correct me if I am wrong. If I can How do I do it ? Its the support for LTS release by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no different repositories for desktop and server packages (hence you can install all available server components in a desktop installation). The difference between desktop and server support with an LTS is just, that **server-related** packages get updated two years longer. So you won't get five years support for e.g. GNOME applications just because you installed the server version.

Comment: does that mean that something like apache2 or mysql-server will get updates for 5 years even though I install desktop edition ?

Comment: Exactly, but keep in mind that those are security updates.